# WinRAR virus scan setup

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, winrar

I noticed WinRAR has the feature to scan archives for virus, however it appears to need setup. This is the window it presents with, how do you configure it for AVs like Windows defender?

[image: screen shot of clicking on Virus Scan button]

Also, is this feature in anyway useful or do modern operating systems do this for you?

Comment: Hmm...You got me thinking. I don't know how to do it, but do we really need it ? Existing antivirus technology and OS's are intelligent enough to scan the files before you or any other application opens it. So is this scan going to find anything that first scan missed ?

Comment: This feature allows you start your AV scan, WinRAR itself, does do the scanning.

Answer (score 4):

According to the answer [here,](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_scanning/support-with-winrarwinzip-to-set-the-virus-scan/) the feature is outdated and useless as of windows 2000.

From the accepted answer:

> The reason is that with Windows 2000 and later, Microsoft added abilities within the operating system itself that allow antivirus and other security applications to gain access to files before the operating system and thus other applications can open them.

Comment: Too bad the link is dead, and archive.org also doesn't have that page archived.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows 10.

In the Virus scanner name text box you should type

```
 C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe
```

In the virus scanner parameters text box you should type

```
 -Scan -Scantype 3 -File "%f"
```

That is it...

Answer (score 2):

Most realtime AV will check as soon as its done downloading, and many can search inside a 'simple' archive.

In theory, you can set this up with a AV that runs in CLI but I can't really find any (easily) and all I'd be doing is reading the documentation back to you. Its handy if you want a second level of defense I suppose but in most cases you shouldn't need it.

You can always test your current AV with the '[eicar test file](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html)' to be sure.